# DB2 connect to remote DB without catalog?

Tags: db2, database-connection, db2-luw

I am trying to connect to DB2 LUW. I am aware that if I catalog tcpip node and the database, I will be able to connect to the DB. Example:

```
db2 catalog tcpip node mynode remote 20.40.20.40 server 5555
db2 catalog database mydb as mydb at node mynode
db2 terminate
db2 connect to mydb user myuser using mypassword
```

However, if I may be required to connect to various DBs, does it mean that I **HAVE TO** undergo the catalog process every time there is a new DB involved? Or is there a way to connect without it? I did find [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/comref/src/tpc/db2z_clpconnectsyntax.html) article from IBM KB, but it's for DB2 z/OS. Currently if I try the following syntax:

```
db2 connect to 20.40.20.40:5555/mydb user myuser using mypassword
```

I get an error:

```
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "20.40.20.40:5555/mydb" was found following "TO".  Expected tokens may include:  "<database-alias>".  SQLSTATE=42601
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this [with CLPPlus](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.clpplus.doc/doc/t0053826.html), which is written in Java and therefore uses a JDBC driver:

```
clpplus myuser@20.40.20.40:5555/mydb
```

but not with the traditional CLP.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [IBM data server driver configuration file](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.config.doc/doc/c0054555.html), where you may specify your databases without cataloging them. There is a detailed description about the format and how to do this.
One may use a simple wrapper which parses the "URL" passed and generates such a configuration file on the fly.
We must call it namely in the `dot space filename` mode.

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Usage: . ./db2connect host:port/dbname USER username [USING password]" >&2
  exit 1
fi

DSN=${1}
CFGFILE=./db2dsdriver.cfg.$$
dbname=${DSN#*/}
hp=${DSN%/*}
host=${hp%:*}
port=${hp#*:}

cat > ${CFGFILE} <<EOF
<configuration>
  <dsncollection>
    <dsn alias="${dbname}" name="${dbname}" host="${host}" port="${port}"/>
  </dsncollection>
  <databases>
    <database name="${dbname}" host="${host}" port="${port}"/>
  </databases>
</configuration>
EOF

cfg_bkp=${DB2DSDRIVER_CFG_PATH}
export DB2DSDRIVER_CFG_PATH=${CFGFILE}
shift
db2 connect to ${dbname} "$@"
export DB2DSDRIVER_CFG_PATH=${cfg_bkp}
rm -f ${CFGFILE}
```

Does it work for you?

Comment: Is'nt that just a form of catalog action by another name ?

Comment: It depends on how you interpret the `catalog action` term. DB2 documentation describes the [CATALOG DATABASE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001936.html) command as registering a database in the system catalog. We don't touch the system catalog with the db2dsdriver.cfg file. Unfortunately, DB2 CLP can't use DSN-less connectivity like CLI applications with the [SQLDriverConnect](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.cli.doc/doc/r0000584.html) function.

Comment: Agrteed. The original question does not suggest any motivation, but the suggestion is the avoidance of prior-configuration before connect, and as we know it's not possible for CLP , but is possible with CLPPlus via jdbc.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have created catalog then even no require to pass IP address and port detail it will connect easily to that database(just make an alias of database) only where you have made catalog like an steps below.

1. db2 catalog TCPIP node mynode remote XX.XX.XX.XX server 50000 --> Normal step.
2. db2 catalog database mydatabase as AKUMAR at node mynode --> AKUMAR is the alias of mydatabase
3. db2 connect to akumar user userid using pwd it will connect to remote database only which has supplied db IP(XX.XX.XX.XX)